# My component re-render after i try to search for an element in a useState array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am currently building a React project, so I made a search Input and when I type something in that Input field my hole component re-renders causing an API recall and deleting the text in my Input. I tried merging both the search component with Home component and the same problem appears.
I want my component to call the api only one time, and I am trying to filter the response depending on the input type.

please help!!
Here is my Home component:

```
import { useContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import CountryThumb from '../Components/CountryThumb';
import ThemeContext from '../Components/ColorPalette';
import { Themes } from '../Components/ColorPalette';
import Search from '../Components/Search';
import Filter from '../Components/Filter';

const Grid = styled.main`
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  column-gap: 60px;
  row-gap: 40px;
  @media (max-width: 375px) {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(1, 1fr);
  }
`;
export default function Home() {
  const [Countries, setCountries] = useState([]);
  const [SearchTerms, setSearchTerms] = useState('');
  const { Theme } = useContext(ThemeContext);
  const style = Theme == 'light' ? Themes.light : Themes.dark;

  useEffect(() => {
    getCountries();
  }, []);
  const Main = styled.main`
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    padding: 20px 100px;
    background-color: ${Theme == 'light' ? style.background : style.background};
    @media (max-width: 375px) {
      padding: 40px 25px;
    }
  `;

  const getCountries = () => {
    axios
      .get('https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all')
      .then((res) => setCountries(res.data))
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Main>
        <Search handleSearch={(e) => setSearchTerms(e.target.value)} />
        <Filter />
        <Grid>
          {Countries.slice(0, 12)
            .filter((e) => {
              if (SearchTerms == '') {
                return e;
              } else if (
                e.name.toLowerCase().includes(SearchTerms.toLowerCase())
              ) {
                return e;
              }
            })
            .map((e) => (
              <CountryThumb props={e} />
            ))}
        </Grid>
      </Main>
    </>
  );
}
```

And here is my Search component:

```
import { useContext, useState } from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import ThemeContext, { Themes } from './ColorPalette';
function Search({ handleSearch }) {
  const { Theme } = useContext(ThemeContext);
  const style = Theme == 'light' ? Themes.light : Themes.dark;
  const Svg = styled.svg`
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    color: ${style.text};
  `;
  const Wrapper = styled.div`
    background-color: ${style.element};
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 10px ${style.shadow};
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 0 20px;
    margin: 40px 0;
  `;
  const CInput = styled.input`
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    padding: 15px 120px 15px 20px;
    font-size: 1rem;
    color: ${style.text};
    background: none;
  `;
  return (
    <>
      <Wrapper>
        <Svg
          xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'
          class='h-6 w-6'
          fill='none'
          viewBox='0 0 24 24'
          stroke='currentColor'
        >
          <path
            strokeLinecap='round'
            strokeLinejoin='round'
            strokeWidth='2'
            d='M21 21l-6-6m2-5a7 7 0 11-14 0 7 7 0 0114 0z'
          />
        </Svg>
        <CInput
          type='text'
          name='Search'
          onInput={handleSearch}
          placeholder='Search for a country ...'
        />
      </Wrapper>
    </>
  );
}

export default Search;
```

Comment: I saw api only call one time. Your search don't call api

Comment: One thing i notice is your are not syncing your input value with the state . You need to do this in your input `value={SearchTerms}` . API call will not be called each time because you have `[]` as dependency so it will called only once .

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you change anything in state your component will rerender so it is normal behaviour. However you have dependency array in useEffect that calls api so this function should run only one time, maybe you didnt have array before and forgot to save.